# Nice and easy way to move Table View Cells onto one single row under a section in a UITableViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

What would be the best way to make all the Table View Cells under a Table View section be on one row as if they were grid squares? I want to still use UITableView but just make the cells single square blocks that together fill up an entire row. (It would be similar to a Collection View except I want to use a UITableView to accomplish this).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't a nice and easy way.  Drop the table view and go with Richard's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableView is single column and linear.  You can't do what you're describing with it.  That's the purpose of the UICollectionView; it's not limited in the format of the cells.

Comment: Is there a way for me to move them at all on the storyboard?